# ekf_node doesn't work when use_sim_time is set to True

Tags: navigation, ros2, robot-localization

I have ROS2/Python/Gazebo project, and I use robot localization like this:

```
    robot_localization_node = Node(
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='ekf_node',
        name='ekf_filter_node',
        namespace='',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[ 
            os.path.join(def_bringup_dir, 'config', 'temp.yaml'),
            {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time }
        ],
    )
```

I only have /odom and /imu in my yaml file.

Now, if I set use_sim_time to False, I can see filtered odometry messages. If set to True - no messages.

I have checked all other nodes, looks like they have use_sim_time set to True.

I understand that "something is wrong", but I would appreciate any suggestions in terms "where to look".

=========== Update

I think I was able to narrow it:
/clock
isn't being published.

Here is how I launch Gazebo:

```
gazebo_node = ExecuteProcess( cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world, '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', '--use-sim-time'], output='screen')
```

Still no idea how to fix it. –

===== More Updates

Even more info, maybe someone can suggest:

```
gazebo_node = ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world, '-s', 
        'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', '-r' '-sim-time'],
    output='screen')        
arrNodes.append(gazebo_node)

# ros2_node = ExecuteProcess(
#         cmd=['ros2', 'param', 'set', '/gazebo', 'use_sim_time', use_sim_time],
#         output='screen')
# arrNodes.append(ros2_node)

# Replaced by a single call below
# start_gazebo_server_cmd = ExecuteProcess(
#     cmd=['gzserver', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so', world, '-r' '-sim-time'],
#     cwd=[def_launch_dir], output='screen')
# arrNodes.append(start_gazebo_server_cmd)
```

If comments are switched, i.e. if I start client and server separately, /clock is published. Though, RViz doesn't receive robot position, and shows white outline, instead of a model.

I would definitely like to make first (combined) approach work, but not sure how to make it publish /clock

Comment: Updated above code with new info

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to start the ros gazebo bridge:

```
ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /clock@rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock[ignition.msgs.Clock
```

Depending on the Gazebo version, you might need to change `ignition.msgs.Clock` to `gz.msgs.Clock` in above command, due to the rename of 'Ignition Gazebo' to 'Gazebo Sim'.

https://index.ros.org/p/ros_gz_bridge/

Comment: I'll try, thank you. Yet, note that when I call client and server separately, /clock is published. Which means that maybe there is a direct approach, like some argument that I don't know about.

Comment: BTW, I have Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0: does it use bridge? I thought it doesn't.

Comment: And I use ROS2 Galactic.

Comment: I mean, I think it should work without bridge - am I correct?

Comment: I was referring to Gazebo Sim, i.e. "New Gazebo". Gazebo 11 is "Gazebo Classic". Not sure if it also needs the bridge...

Answer (score 0):

Funny error. In lidar, base frame was set to base_footprint, instead of base_link. No idea why it blocks publishing /clock, but...

The working project can be downloaded at [robotics.snowcron.com](https://robotics.snowcron.com)